# Error/bug when searching for an app on the start menu on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

The Start menu styling/format is not not working correctly on Windows 10 when searching for apps on the Start menu. Please see screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you installed any 3rd party apps or is this a fresh install of Windows?

Comment: same time it will show correct and some time not. I don't know why and
I  had not installed any 3rd party apps or tools

Comment: Did u try performing `sfc /scannow` from a command prompt or powershell running as admin?

Comment: when getting next windows update from MS, it will work correctly.
 Thank @slayemoah